# how to rewrite mongo shell code to regular python file?

Tags: python, mongodb

The below code exist inside a python file I run at cli as 'python test.py '....

```
import pymongo

from pymongo import Connection


connection = Connection('localhost', 27017)

db = connection.school

data = db.students.aggregate(
 { $match :  { 'scores.type': 'homework'   },
 { $project: { id : $_id,
         name : $name,
         scores : $scores
 },
 {  $unwind:  "$scores" },
 { $group : {
     _id : "$id",
     minScore: { $min :"$scores.score" },
     maxScore: { $max: "$scores.score" }
   }
 });

for _id in data:

    print _id
    # NOTE: this can only be done ONCE...first find lowest_id then
    # remove it by uncommenting the line below...then recomment line.

    # db.students.remove(data)
```

when I run this code I get this error...

```
  File "test.py", line 11
{ $match :  { 'scores.type': 'homework'   },
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I rewrite this code so it works correctly from inside my test.py python file?

Comment: aggregate takes an array (or list) so you need to pass it [ ] where each element is a document { }

Answer (score 1):

You have a few syntax issues.

First, pipeline is an array (a list in Python) where you are trying to pass multiple pipeline elements as separate parameters.

Second, you need to quote the pipeline operators, such as $match: `'$match'`

Here is a page that has some nice examples: 
 http://blog.pythonisito.com/2012/06/using-mongodbs-new-aggregation.html